# Reading excel file from ASP.NET Core HttpContext.Request of multipart/form-data content?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, parsing, multipartform-data

Almost all libraries I've searched for require a `FileStream` to read excel files - none work with a `MultipartReaderStream`, used by `MultipartSection.Body` property.

Any suggestions? Basically any library that supports reading an excel file via a `TextReader` would work with a `MultipartReaderStream`, as then you can simply read the stream via the use of a `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your controller looks like, but that's how we do it in out project

```cs
[HttpPost("endpoint")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile([FromForm(Name = "file")]IFormFile file)
{
    using var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream();
    ...
}
```

Comment: we don't use model binding via `IFormFile`, but rather do the process explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming) for uploading large files via streaming, as our files tend to be pretty big. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, seems like I misunderstood the question. ```System.IO.FileStream``` is a class that is designed for physical files on the local disk. So if the library requires it, that means it is not supposed to be used in HTTP server.

Comment: Are you capable of modifying the default buffer size for a `IFormFile`? Because by default any `IFormFile` larger than 64kb gets turned into a temporary file, so I'm wondering if we can increase that limit upto 10 mb's for example?

Comment: Sorry, can't answer that. we deal with small files.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the `MultiPartSection` into a `FileMultipartSection` via a call to `AsFileSection`, which now has a property `FileStream` you can use.

Example:

```
MultipartReader reader = ...
...
MultipartSection section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
FileMultipartSection fileSection = section.AsFileSection();
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure the section actually contains a file, by for example checking the content disposition.